# Get ID pairs between 2 tables with matching child records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with the same structure.

```
FIELD 1      INT
FIELD 2      VARCHAR(32)   -- is a MD5 Hash
```

The query has to get matching FIELD 1 pairs from for records that have the exact combination of values for FIELD 2 in both TABLE 1 and TABLE 2.

These tables are pretty large ( 1 million records between the two ) but are deduced down to an ID and a Hash.

Example data: 

**TABLE 1**

```
1     A
1     B
2     A
2     D
2     E
3     G
3     H
4     E
4     D
4     C
5     E
5     D
```

**TABLE 2**

```
8     A
8     B
9     E
9     D
9     C
10    F
11    G
11    H
12    B
12    D
13    A
13    B
14    E
14    A
```

The results of the query should be

```
8     1
9     4
11    3
13    1
```

I have tried creating a concatenated string of FIELD 2 using a correlated sub-query and FOR XML PATH string trick I read on here but that is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following query also -

```
SELECT t_2.Field_1, t_1.Field_1                          --1
  FROM table_1 t_1, table_2 t_2                          --2
 WHERE t_1.Field_2 = t_2.Field_2                         --3
 GROUP BY t_1.Field_1, t_2.Field_1                       --4
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)                       --5
                     FROM Table_1 t_1_1                  --6
                    WHERE t_1_1.Field_1 = t_1.Field_1)   --7
   AND COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)                       --8
                     FROM Table_2 t_2_1                  --9
                    WHERE t_2_1.Field_1 =t_2.Field_1)    --10
```

**Edit**

First the requested set of result is the combination of Field1 from both the tables where respective Field2 is exactly same.

so for that you can use one method which I have posted above.

Here 
query will take the data from both the table based on field2 values (from line 1 to line 3)
then it will group the data based on field1 from table1 and field1 from table2 (line 4)

till this step you will get the result having field1 from table1 and field2 from table2 where it exists (at least one) matching based on field2 from tables for respective field1 values.

after this you just need to filter the result for correct (exactly same values for field2 values for respective field1 column value). so that you can make condition on row count.

> here my assumption is that you don't have multiple values for field1 and field2 combination in either tables

means following rows will not be present -

1    b
1    b

In any of the tables.

if so, the rows count got for table1 and table2 for same field2 values should be match with the rows present in table1 for field1 and same rows only should present in tables2 for field2 value.

for this condition query has condition on `count(*)` in `having` clause (from line 5 to line 10).

Comment: I gave it a try and ... failed. Yours produces the requested result. So you get my vote. But I cannot seem to wrap my head around your solution. I would be much obliged if you could explain some more about how this works.

Comment: @souplex.. I tried to make is more clear .. please see me edited post.
I know this is still not much clear written even in edited/clarification part.

you are welcome to ask any particular question related to query if you have any..

Comment: I wound up using a Scalar function to Concat the strings in FIELD2 grouped by FIELD1.  I then inner joined on that string.

Comment: Thank you Pratik, together with Gordon's explanation it has become a lot clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain this version of the query:

```
select t1.field1 as t1field1, t2.field1 as t2field1
from (select t1.*,
             count(*) over (partition by field1) as NumField2
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select t2.*,
             count(*) over (partition by field1) as NumField2
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.field2 = t2.field2
where t1.NumField2 = t2.NumField2
group by t1.Field1, t2.Field1
having count(t1.field2) = max(t1.NumField2) and
       count(t2.field2) = max(t2.NumField2)
```

(which is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4704) at SQLFiddle).

The idea is to compare the following counts for each pair of `field1` values.

1. The number of `field2` values on each.
2. The number of `field2` values that they share.

All of these have to be equal.

Each subquery counts the number of values of `field2` on each `field1` value.  For the first rows of your data, this produces:

```
1    A    2
1    B    2
2    A    3
2    D    3
2    E    3
. . .
```

And for the second table

```
8    A    2
8    B    2
9    E    3
9    D    3
9    C    3
```

Next, the `full outer join` is applied, requiring a match on both the count and the `field2` value. This multiplies the data, producing rows such as:

```
1    A    2    8    A    2
1    B    2    8    B    2
2    A    3    NULL NULL NULL
2    D    3    9    D    3
2    E    3    9    E    3
NULL NULL NULL 9    C    3
```

And so on for all the possible combinations.  Note that the `NULL`s appear due to the `full outer join`.

Note that when you have a pair, such as 1 and 8 that match, there are no rows with `NULL` values.  When you have a pair with the same counts but they don't match, then you have `NULL` values.  When you have a pair with different counts, they are filtered out by the `where` clause.

The filtering aggregation step applies these rules to get pairs that meet the first condition but not the second.

The `having` essentially removes any pair that has `NULL` values.  When you `count()` a column, `NULL` values are not included.  In that case, the `count()` on the column is fewer than the number of values expected (`NumField2`).

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response

Comment: A very good and detailed  explanation indeed, it has explained the need for the count comparison very clearly.

Comment: @souplex . . . I have struggled with how to explain this type of query for a while.  There are several ways of writing the query, and I think this version is both fairly efficient and explainable.